# Blessing on drinks made from the 7 species

Tags: halacha, blessing, tractate-brachot, fruits, drinking

According to Halacha, do drinks, such as for example pomegranate juice, made from the 7 species have the same Berakha of when you eat the 7 species or no? The reason I ask is because for example you don’t bentch for liquor, would this be similar or no? Same goes for olive oil, and other liquid products derived from the seven different species.

Comment: Are you talking about an after blessing? That's the only one different for the seven species

Comment: The only fruit juice treated specially is grape juice/wine which has its own before/after blessing. Other fruit juices (incl. other 7 species) have a *sheakol/borei nefashot*. There are some distinctions with olive oil if you drink it for its medicinal properties (where some believe one says *ha-eitz*) but it is rarely practically relevant